# Does forking a repository and modifying the contents violate CC BY-NC-ND 4.0?

Tags: copyright, licensing, creative-commons

I attempted to ask this question on the Github community forums, but it was flagged as spam and awaiting a review before being open again.

I recently picked up the hobby of creative writing in my downtime, and I wanted to use Github to post a web serial novel as `.pdf` files. The issue is, I **don't** want people to modify and redistribute my work. They can download it, even turn it into another format, for example, `.tex`, but I don't want them to modify the text itself (a derivative) and share it.

Before I go any further, I understand I'm using Github in a way it wasn't intended, so it may be difficult to do what I want.

I attempted to research further, and it seems the [`CC BY-NC-ND 4.0`](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/4.0/) licence is what I require.

1. Is `CC BY-NC-ND 4.0` licence correct for my situation?

From the Github's [ToS](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/licensing-a-repository#choosing-the-right-license):

> Note: If you publish your **source code** in a public repository on
> GitHub, according to the Terms of Service, other users of GitHub have
> the right to view and fork your repository.

2. As stated, I can't prohibit someone from forking the repository containing the `.pdf` files, but if they attempted to modify and redistribute the text, they would be in direct violation of the `CC BY-NC-ND 4.0` licence, correct?

The easiest solution would be to not use Github. It might be better to use Amazon KDP, as they are set up to handle this type of situation.

Comment: I *think* your interpretation is correct.  This is the first I've encountered the -ND licenses, though, so I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 1):

> From the Github's [ToS](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/licensing-a-repository#choosing-the-right-license):
>
> > Note: If you publish your **source code** in a public repository on
> > GitHub, according to the Terms of Service, other users of GitHub have
> > the right to view and fork your repository.

Note that what you quoted as "from GitHub's ToS" is *not* a quote from [GitHub's ToS](https://docs.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service). It is a quote from GitHub's *documentation* about how to use the Repository Settings page.

[This is the actual quote from the ToS](https://docs.github.com/en/github/site-policy/github-terms-of-service#5-license-grant-to-other-users), and I believe it is much clearer [**bold** emphasis mine]:

> ## 5. License Grant to Other Users
>
> Any User-Generated Content you post publicly, including issues, comments, and contributions to other Users' repositories, may be **viewed** by others. By setting your repositories to be viewed publicly, you agree to **allow others to view and "fork"** your repositories (this means that **others may make their own copies** of Content from your repositories in repositories they control).
>
> If you set your pages and repositories to be viewed publicly, **you grant each User of GitHub a nonexclusive, worldwide license** to **use, display, and perform** Your Content through the GitHub Service and to **reproduce** Your Content solely on GitHub as permitted through GitHub's functionality (for example, through forking). You **may** grant further rights if you adopt a license. […]

The actual ToS make it very clear that the *only* rights you grant to other users are all about viewing, using, displaying, performing, and copying, but *not* about modification.